# Revit Subtransaction Statement error

Tags: transactions, revit

I have having a problem with this statement:

SubTransaction subTransaction = new SubTransaction(doc);
if (subTransaction.Start() == 1)

Comment: Can you give more info on  the problem or the error?

Comment: ERROR: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Autodesk.Revit.DB.TransactionStatus' and 'int'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message, the problem is with the `if` statement. Try this instead:

```
if (subTransaction.Start() == TransactionStatus.Started) { ... }
```

In .NET, enum values need to be cast to `int` first, if you want to compare them to an `int`. And you probably don't want to be doing that anyway, because that just obscures the value with a magic number.